Myhill-Nerode sentence and the relation $R_L$
Given a finite alphabet $\Sigma$ of size $n\geq 1$, we define the following language over $\Sigma$:
$$L = \left\{ u \sigma v \sigma w \mid \sigma \in \Sigma, u, v, w \in \Sigma^* \right\}
$$
Let $R_L$ denote the set of Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes w.r.t $L$.
How many equivalence classes exist in $R_L$?

$1$
$n+1$
$3n+1$
$2^n + 1$
$\aleph_0$

Define the equivalence classes.
My attempts:
I think the answer is $2n+1$ as we have one class for the empty word,
$n$ classes for words that contain some letter exactly once, and another
$n$ classes for words contain some letter at least twice.
I'm not sure whether a word that contains some letter $a$ 3 times is in $L$, and should it be in the same equivalent class of a word that contains the letter $a$ 2 times?
Perhaps  $u$ and $v$ must not contains $\sigma$ and so $\sigma$ needs to appear exactly twice for the input word to be in $L$?

Define $R_L$. Also, this website isn't the place for "do my homework"-style questions.

not my homework, a question from a past exam from few years ago. I think the answer is 2n+1: 1 class for the empty word, n classes for words contains the letter sigma exactly once, n classes for words contains the letter sigma twice or more. total of 2n+1. i'm not sure if a word contains sigma for example 3 times is a word in L? or does u,v must not contains sigma and so sigma need to appear exactly twice to be a word in L. And not sure about my answer in general.

@yehr Can you edit the question and add your attempts/thoughts? Also, see my hints in the answer. You have more than $n$ classes corresponding to words that contain some letter once, because you can have a different letter that appears also once in the same word. Far more... that's why I hinted to consider subsets (Hint 1).

Done, thanks. I understand from your hint that the answer should be $2^n+1$, which is all the ways to choose a subset of letters from $\Sigma$. Because if i have a shared letter between subset S and T, then adding this latter to a word from both classes will determine both words are in the language. And if i have a letter not shared between the subsets, then there is a letter that will determine one word in the language and the other one not. Hence, I must have in the equivalence classes all words above the same subset of $\Sigma$, with at least one appearance of each letter in the subset.

Plus one class for the empty string

@BaderAbuRadi something still doesn't adds up to me.. If i define the classes as all the words above a subset of $\Sigma$ with at least one letter of each letter from the subset, then for example for the class of words above a subset of {a,b,c} i would have the words $abc$ and $abbc$ in the same equivalent class, but the empty string would be a separating suffix between the two words. so they can't be in the same class. Or is the extra class in $2^n+1$ is for all strings containing a letter twice? but then to which class the empty string would go? WDYT? thanks for you help!

@yehr Exactly. Each subset defines a class of words having every letter in the subset appearing exactly once. The empty word corresponds to the empty subset, and all words that have some letter appearing twice are equivalent (these words reach an accepting-sink in the minimal DFA). So the plus one is for the latter class of words containing some letter at least twice, and not for the empty word. If its still not clear, we can move to chat to avoid long discussion in the comment section.

Note that $u, v$ and $w$ can contain any letter. Therefore, $L$ is the language of all words that contain some letter at least twice. In particular, a word that contains some letter 3 times is in $L$. Note also that the words $ab$ and $ac$ are not Myhill-Nerode equivalent although they contain the same letter $a$ once. For exapme, $b$ is a separating suffix between the latter words. Further hints:
Hint 1: for every subset $S\subset \Sigma$, consider a word $w_S\in \Sigma^*$ such that $|w_S| = |S|$ and every letter in $S$ appears in $w_S$. What can you say about $w_S$ and $w_T$ for distinct subsets $S$ and $T$?
Hint 2: try to build a minimal DFA for $L$.

Look at a string x. If x contains some letter twice, then xy is in the language for every string y. Or x consists of k different letters in any order. Then xy is in the language if either y contains one of the k letters of x, or if y contains one of the letters not in x twice. If x and x’ don’t contain the exact same letters then the two sets are different.
So we get one equivalence class for every subset of $\Sigma$, and one for all strings containing a letter twice, for a total of $2^n + 1$ equivalence classes.
